# How can I add a compositingFilter to NStextfield

Tags: swift, macos

Im declaring an outlet called timeField from an NSTextField

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeField: NSTextField!
```

I want to programatically apply a compositing filter called "addition" to the timeField. I can do this in Xcode gui, but I really want to do it programatically, Apples docs are confusing.

My guess was:

```
let compositingFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")
   timeField.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode.compositingFilter
```

Comment: Can you show how you would do it in the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let compositing = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")
textField.compositingFilter = compositing
```